# Headless shopify, but still use shopify as a cms/page builder for the customer instead of third party cms

Tags: content-management-system, shopify, headless

I have a customer that wants to do a headless shopify sollution(ill probably go with next js commerce). And with that you will probably miss out on using the theme editor for the customer to manage content on pages(like drag/drop building blocks). Is it still possible to handle this with shopify as a cms while doing headless? or is the only way to make this work to implement a third party cms like Sanity or Shogun.

Hope my question makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the 3rd party drag and drop builders, but for Shopify pages, blogs and articles, you can use the Shopify API to retrieve the data. You can use Shopify [REST API](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2021-10/resources/page#top) or [GraphQL API](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2021-10/objects/OnlineStoreArticle#top). Using these, you should be able to get data for

- Pages
- Blogs
- Articles
- Comments

Most of the required API responses will include raw html data that you can render via your headless application.